Semisimplicity of modules
Let $R$ be a ring with unity $1\neq 0$ (may be non-commutative).
A left $R$-module $M$ is said to be semisimple if it is direct sum of simple submodules. The direct sum may be finite or infinite.
Consider following statements.

(1) $M$ is direct sum of simple submodules: $M=\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i$.


(2) Every submodule of $M$ has a complement.

I want to see whether these are equivalent if $I$ is infinite.
$(1)\Longrightarrow (2)$ can be proved using Zorn's lemma.
I do not know whether $(2)\Longrightarrow (1)$? Could anyone state whether this implication is valid? (I will try to prove then; remember - direct sum is infinite).
The problem I am facing is: under assumption of (2), can we deduce that $M$ contains some simple submodules?

Hint: show that if (2) holds for $M$, then it holds for every submodule. Now take a cyclic submodule $U=Rm$. Use Zorn to show that $U$ contains a maximal submodule $U’$ not containing $m$, and take a complement of $U’$ in $U$.

For a proof see Lam’s A First Course on non-Commutative Rings.

A sketch of the path to prove $(2)\implies (1)$. From here we assume $(2)$ holds for $M$. Keep in mind that this implies (2) holds for all submodules of $M$ as well.
Lemma 1: Every nonzero submodule of $M$ contains a simple submodule.
Proof: Let $N$ be a nonzero submodule of $N$. It suffices to show a cyclic submodule $nR$ of $N$ contains a simple submodule.  Since $nR$ is cyclic, it contains a maximal submodule. Call it $A$. Because $nR$ has the condition (2) assumed above, let $B$ be the complement of $A$ in $nR$ so that $A\oplus B=nR$. By maximality of $A$, $B$ is a simple submodule of $nR$, and furthermore $B$ is a simple submodule of $N$.
Lemma 2: The sum of all simple submodules of $M$ equals $M$.
Proof: If that sum is proper in $M$, its nonzero complement contains a simple submodule by Lemma 1. But this is absurd, since that simple submodule should be part of the sum of simple modules, and can't be disjoint in the complement.
Lemma 3: A sum of simple modules can be re-expressed as a direct sum of those simple modules. (I'm pretty sure you've seen this already.)
